# Wrap legend text in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Whilst producing graphs using ggplot2, I have some long legend names which I wish to wrap over two lines. For example:

```
a <- (1:10)
b <- c(1,1.5,2,4,5,5.3,7,9,9.5,9.8)
places = c("Birmingham","Chester-le-street","Cambridge", "Newcastle-upon-Tyne","Peterborough","Cambridge", "Newcastle-upon-Tyne","Peterborough","Liverpool","Stratford-upon-Avon")
df1 = data.frame(a,b,places)
library(ggplot2)
i = ggplot(df1, aes(x=a, y=b)) + geom_point(aes(colour = places), size=3) + opts(legend.position="bottom")
```

How would I go about wrapping the legend items when the box is set to be at the bottom - say in 2 or 3 lines?  At the moment the seven items of the legend are next to each other.  I would prefer that they are displayed in two rows (with say four towns on the top row and three towns on the second row).

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I would split your question into two separate questions.  One of which would be answered by my response (wrapping the text as was apparent in the original question) and a second for how to create multicolumn legends with ggplot.  PS:  the location of the legend should not change much for the response to your question).

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Ok, given your edits, you probably wanted this:

```
library(scales)
i + guides(colour = guide_legend(nrow = 2))
```

But you may find that you still want to employ the text wrapping technique as well, to get it to fit.

Comment: Besides `colour`, this also works for other aesthetics such as `guides(linetype=guide_legend(nrow=2))`.

Answer (score 24):

From your example:

```
df1$places<-sub("-", "- \n ", df1$places)  

i = ggplot(df1, aes(x=a, y=b)) + geom_point(aes(colour = places), size=3)
```

[image]

Notes:
 - You can use gsub to replace all the "-" with "- \n "

Comment: Thanks @Etienne Low-Décarie, but this is not quite what I want. I still want the legend at the botton, but the legend text is very long.  So instead of the 7 labels on one long row, I want them on two rows (keeping the graph a similar shape to how it is on your example).

Comment: @KatieT You need to be clearer about whether you want to wrap the _text labels_ in the legend across 2 lines, or the _legend items_ themselves, or both. You question only mentioned wrapping the 'legend names', which is what this answer addresses.

Comment: Do you know how to do this with the legend's title?

Answer (score 15):

Another way to wrap the legend labels which I found very handy is the following (all credits to https://sites.google.com/site/simonthelwall/home/r/ggplot2#TOC-Wrapping-legend-labels):

```
a <- (1:10)
b <- c(1,1.5,2,4,5,5.3,7,9,9.5,9.8)
places = c("Birmingham","Chester-le-street","Cambridge", "Newcastle-upon-Tyne","Peterborough","Cambridge", "Newcastle-upon-Tyne","Peterborough","Liverpool","Stratford-upon-Avon")
df1 = data.frame(a,b,places)
library(ggplot2)
i = ggplot(df1, aes(x=a, y=b)) + geom_point(aes(colour = places), size=3) 

i + scale_colour_discrete(labels = function(x) str_wrap(x, width = 5))
```

[image]