# ggplot2: Top legend key symbol size changes with legend key label

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

**The Problem**

I want to place the legend of my plot above the plot. I also want to place the legend key symbol (colored squares) above the legend key labels (legend text). Unfortunately, when I do this, the legend key symbol "stretches" to fit the size of the label. I imagine ggplot2 is working fine, but how could I manually override this feature?

How do I keep a consistent legend key symbol across the top with labels of variable lengths?

**Reproducible Example**

(*It's not necessarily a minimal example, just in case the structure of my actual code, like the `coord_flip` and `fill` calls, has an impact*)

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

dataFrame <- diamonds %>%
              group_by(color, cut) %>%
              summarise(count = n()) %>%
              group_by(color) %>%
              mutate(percent = count/sum(count),
                    pretty_label = paste0(round(percent*100, 1), "%")) %>%
              ungroup()

p <- ggplot(data = dataFrame, mapping = aes(x=color, y = percent, group = cut))+
      geom_bar(aes(fill = cut), stat = "identity", position = "fill")+
      geom_text(aes(label = pretty_label), position=position_fill(vjust=0.5), colour="white", stat = "identity")+
      coord_flip()+
      theme(legend.position="top")+
      guides(fill = guide_legend(label.position = "bottom", reverse = TRUE))

plot(p)
```

[image: legend symbols stretch with labels]

Notice how each of the legend symbols are different sizes, depending on the length of the label.

**What I have already tried**

I imagine it has something to do with guides, but I can't seem to get it right. Using the plot above (`p`), I have tried the following and more:

1. From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16356206/9017311) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15059093/9017311): `p + guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=3)))`
2. From [here](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/guide_legend.html): `p + guides(colour = guide_legend(keywidth = .5, keyheight = .5))` 
   and 
   `p + guides(colour = guide_legend(keywidth = unit(.5, "cm"), keyheight = unit(.5, "cm")))`
3. From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10335273/9017311): (Trying to wrap labels) `p + guides(color = guide_legend(nrow = 2))`

I've tried other, less "logical" attempts just because. None of which worked.

**Final Thoughts**

I could just be having a difficult time knowing what to search for. I am always open to figuring out the problem myself, if you are able to point me in the right direction. Any additional resources are more than welcome.

Thanks, in advance!

**Session Output**

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] bindrcpp_0.2.2 ggplot2_3.0.0  dplyr_0.7.6   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.18      bindr_0.1.1       magrittr_1.5      tidyselect_0.2.4  munsell_0.5.0     colorspace_1.3-2  viridisLite_0.3.0
 [8] R6_2.2.2          rlang_0.2.1       plyr_1.8.4        tools_3.5.1       grid_3.5.1        gtable_0.2.0      withr_2.1.2      
[15] yaml_2.1.19       lazyeval_0.2.1    assertthat_0.2.0  digest_0.6.17     tibble_1.4.2      purrr_0.2.5       glue_1.2.0       
[22] labeling_0.3      compiler_3.5.1    pillar_1.2.3      scales_0.5.0      pkgconfig_2.0.1
```

Comment: All the options you have under "What I have already tried" work to some extent, if you replace `colour` with `fill`, e.g. `p + guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=3)))`. You have a fill scale, not a colour scale.

Comment: I thought that might be the case too. I tried it on my actual data, but my labels were too long and I wasn't increasing the size by enough. If the size is less than the longest label, it doesn't have an impact (at least for me). I neglected to try those possibilities on the example I gave, but that might have led me in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know if there's a way to control the width of the legend color boxes separately from the text (other than hacking the legend grobs). However, if you add `legend.key.width=unit(1.5, "cm")` in your theme statement, all of the color boxes will be expanded to the same width (you may have to tweak the 1.5 up or down a bit to get the desired box widths).

```
library(scales)

ggplot(dataFrame, aes(x=color, y = percent))+
  geom_bar(aes(fill = cut), stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(aes(label = pretty_label), position=position_fill(vjust=0.5), 
            colour="white", size=3)+
  coord_flip()+
  theme(legend.position="top",
        legend.key.width=unit(1.5, "cm"))+
  guides(fill = guide_legend(label.position = "bottom", reverse = TRUE)) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels=percent)
```

[image]

You can save a little space by putting `Very Good` on two lines:

```
library(forcats)

ggplot(dataFrame, aes(x=color, y = percent, fill = fct_recode(cut, "Very\nGood"="Very Good")))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(aes(label = pretty_label), position=position_fill(vjust=0.5), 
            colour="white", size=3)+
  coord_flip()+
  theme(legend.position="top",
        legend.key.width=unit(1.2, "cm"))+
  guides(fill = guide_legend(label.position = "bottom", reverse = TRUE)) +
  labs(fill="Cut") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels=percent)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I believe I tried your solution on my actual data, but the labels were so long and I wasn't setting the width long enough. So if the labels are longer than the width you provide, it doesn't have an impact, which makes sense. Additionally, the `fct_recode` helped a lot, and I was able to abbreviate some of the labels. I appreciate your help.